# Arguments syntax in Robot framework Gherkin style

Tags: robotframework, gherkin

How could I place arguments in the middle of the test step description?

When I create a step like this everything goes OK (arguments are at the end of the step):

```
*** Test Cases ***
Scenario: Login as a valid user
     When user is logged in as:    user1    password1

*** Keywords ***
user is logged in as:
[Arguments]    ${arg_user}    ${arg_pass}
Click Link    id=loginLink
Page Should Contain    Use a local account to log in
Input Text    id=UserName    ${arg_user}
Input Text    id=Password    ${arg_pass}
Click Button    xpath=//*[@id="loginForm"]/form/fieldset/input
```

How does the `*** Test Cases ***` and `*** Keywords ***` look like for a step like this:

```
When user user1 is logged in with the following password: password1
```

, where *user1* is the first argument and *password1* is the second one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using embedded arguments, embed them in the keyword name and omit the use of `[Arguments]`. It's also a good practice to put the arguments in quotes, though it's not strictly necessary. In my experience it helps to reduce ambiguity.

Here is an example in the pipe-delimited format:

```
*** Keywords ***
| When user "${user}" is logged in with the following password: "${password}"
| | ${result}= | Set Variable | username is ${user} and password is ${password}
| | [Return] | ${result}

*** Test Cases ***
| Example of how to use keyword with embedded arguments
| | ${result}= | When user "bob" is logged in with the following password: "superSecret!"
| | Should be equal | ${result} | username is bob and password is superSecret!
```